# How to connect unified database

Tags: database, selenium

My application still using Unified database and i am trying to automated that using selenium Java.
Could anyone please help me to identify driver or api i should use to connect to database.
I tried

Option 1

`Class.forName("com.imaginary.sql.msql.MsqlDriver"); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "borg", "");`

Option 2

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
c =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:xxx/DATABASE", "USERNAME", "Password");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of search i have found my answer.To connect unified database ,compatible driver is SimbaJDBC. Hope this will help others who are in same boat.